# Why do I have to re-set env vars in tmux when I re-attach?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, tmux

I mainly work on a mac and ssh/tmux attach to a Linux machine to do my work. I have ssh-agent running on the Linux machine. I have

`set -g update-environment "SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_ASKPASS WINDOWID SSH_CONNECTION XAUTHORITY"`

in my `.tmux.conf`. Yet, whenever I re-attach to this session, I have to run

```
tmux setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

in order for new tmux windows to have `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set correctly. I would prefer to not have to do this. Any ideas?

#### Update

I think I'm not explaining this well. Here's my shell function to open a shell on a remote machine:

```
sshh () {
    tmux -u neww -n ${host} "ssh -Xt ${host} $*"
}
```

When tmux runs this ssh command, `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is **not** set, even though it **is** set in my local environment. If I put this in tmux's environment with the `setenv` command above, everything works fine. My question is, why do I have to run the setenv command at all?

#### Update 2

More information:

When I attach to an existing session, `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is not set in the tmux environment (or global environment).

```
% tmux showenv | grep -i auth_sock
-SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

If I set it manually, things work:

```
% tmux setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

If I detach and re-attach, `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` goes back to not being set.

Comment: This isn't about SSH at all, is it? Which environment variables do you have in a new shell, what is the output of `env`?

Comment: What shell are you using on the Mac? Bash?

Comment: @HaukeLaging It's really about tmux.

Comment: @slm I'm using zsh.

Comment: What about the existing windows? Do they still work?

Comment: @HaukeLaging If you mean by 'work', can I ssh without re-entering my key's passphrase, then yes, existing windows work because `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set in their local environment.

Comment: @ChrisW. Then $SSH_AUTH_SOCK does not point back to your client but to a local ssh-agent which keeps running after you close the SSH connection? If so then djf's explanation (interesting as it is) does not help I guess. What happens if you detach from `tmux` and reattach without closing the SSH connection? Is it possible for you to log in locally?

Comment: ssh-agent is running on the same machine with the tmux session. I'm ssh'ing to other hosts from that tmux session. Does that help?

Comment: @ChrisW. This is rather strange. Are you saying that SSH_AUTH_SOCK is being removed from the environment of the new windows? Tmux' man page states that **update-environment** will remove variables _"that do not exist in the source environment [...] as if -r was given to the set-environment command"_. I think I'm missing a piece of the puzzle, could you perhaps show how you start the ssh-agent? Also, what do **show-environment** and **show-environment -g** right after you connect with sshh() ? If you just ssh into the remote machine, what does **printenv** show?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured this out. Short answer, I needed to remove `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` from `update-environment`. Since it was in that list, the value was being blown away every time I reattached. Thanks to @djf for the clue. The salient bit from the tmux(1) man page in the `update-environment` section:

> Any variables that do not exist in the source environment are set to be removed from the session environment (as if -r was given to the set-environment command).

Comment: @ChrisW. could you please be a little big more clear? I do think that I have the same problem: sometimes the agent stops working when I reattach tmux sessions. It make some sense as the SSH connection is new and when I ssh it will start a new agent. What do I have to change in order to make it work? I hope it's something that I can run as I do not want to have to reconfigure each machine I am ssh-ing into. -- Now I do have an ssh wrapper that starts tmux remotely or restores existing connections, probably I could do something before restoring the tmux.

Comment: @ChrisW. short answers are nice sometimes, but could you please give a long answer? I'm struggling with getting this to work and nothing in this post is working for me.

Comment: @sorin @redbmk Sorry about that. This is the only line I had to change in my `.tmux.conf` to get this to work:

    `set -g update-environment "SSH_ASKPASS WINDOWID SSH_CONNECTION XAUTHORITY"`

Are you seeing problems with `ssh` or environment variables in general?

Answer (score 47):

Since I received the Bounty, I'll repost my key-comment for completeness sake - and to avoid setting visitors with the same problem on the wrong track:

### Tmux will remove Environment Variables

Tmux' man page states that update-environment will remove variables *"that do not exist in the source environment [...] as if -r was given to the set-environment command".*

Apparently that what caused the issue. See [Chris' response below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76475/21464). However, I still can't imagine how the variable could be absent in the "source environment" and yet be valid in the newly created tmux window...

---

Previous Answer:

### How SSH forwarding works

On the remote machine, take a look at the environment of your shell after establishing the SSH connection:

```
user@remote:~$ env | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=68.38.123.35 45926 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
SSH_CONNECTION=68.38.123.35 48926 10.1.35.23 22
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-hRNwjA1342/agent.1342
```

The important one here is SSH_AUTH_SOCK which is currently set to some file in /tmp. If you examine this file, you'll see that it's a Unix domain socket -- and is connected to the particular instance of ssh that you connected in on. Importantly, this changes every time you connect.

As soon as you log out, that particular socket file is gone. Now, if you go and reattach your tmux session, you'll see the problem. It has the environment from when tmux was originally launched -- which could have been weeks ago. That particular socket is long since dead.

### Solution

Since we know the problem has to do with knowing where the currently live SSH authentication socket is, let's just put it in a predictable place!

In your .bashrc or .zshrc file on the remote machine, add the following:

```
# Predictable SSH authentication socket location.
SOCK="/tmp/ssh-agent-$USER-screen"
if test $SSH_AUTH_SOCK && [ $SSH_AUTH_SOCK != $SOCK ]
then
    rm -f /tmp/ssh-agent-$USER-screen
    ln -sf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SOCK
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SOCK
fi
```

I don't think you even have to put an 'update-environment command' in your tmux.conf. According to the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html), SSH_AUTH_SOCK is already covered by default.

### Credit

My response is an excerpt of [this blog post](http://qq.is/article/ssh-keys-through-screen) by Mark 'xb95' Smith who explains the same problem for [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. My question is not about setting my `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in new shells, it's about setting `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in new tmux windows before .bashrc/.zshrc is sourced.

Comment: @ChrisW. I assumed that the script should be put in the rc file of your login shell on the remote machine. If you login, a new shell is spawned, SSH_AUTH_SOCK is changed and **exported**. When you then start tmux, it will inherit SSH_AUTH_SOCK from the parent environment. Since the value of SSH_AUTH_SOCK is now fixed, tmux should keep working on subsequent logins... Maybe I misunderstood the problem

Comment: I guess my confusion is about the environment in which ssh is run by tmux in the context of a new window (e.g. ```tmux neww ssh somehost```).

Comment: One problem with this approach is the a 2nd SSH connection to the machine will overwrite the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. This approach only works while the tmux session is open via the most recent SSH connection.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tmux to handle my ssh-agent, I have bash handle it with:

```
### SSH Agent ### {{{
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

function start_agent {
    echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add;
}

## Source SSH settings, if applicable
if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
  else
    start_agent;
fi
### End SSH Agent ### }}}
```

I have this in my ~/[bashrc](http://github.com/demure/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc), and it works great.

Comment: `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set properly in my shells, but when I do something like `tmux neww ssh somehost`, I will be prompted for my passphrase to unlock my private key **unless** I run `tmux setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/49395839/241025. Since this page came up first in my Google searches, I wanted to post a summary version of it here.

To get each tmux session to have a set of custom environment variables, you have to add the values to tmux's per-session environment variables. Here's an example of how to do it.

```
tmux new-session -s one
tmux setenv FOO foo-one
export FOO='foo-one'
```

The last step of explicitly exporting FOO is needed so that the current pane will pick up the environment variable. Any subsequent panes or windows you create for this tmux session will inherit FOO, but it won't show up in other sessions.

Answer (score 0):

djf's explanation brings another possible solution to my mind:

Before `tmux` / `screen` is running:

1. Log in.
2. Start an instance of `ssh-agent`.
3. Start `tmux` / `screen` with the environment variable(s) for this `ssh-agent`.

This could not use SSH forwarding to the client but that was not asked for.

Comment: `ssh-agent` doesn't bind to TTY, why should it be killed on logout(?) — why using `nohup`?

Comment: @poige Correct.