# How can I forward a already forwarded ssh key into tmux?

Tags: shell, ssh, tmux

I'm connecting through SSH from a machine where my keys are stored, forwarding to a second machine, and then try to use the keys from within tmux. I appear to "loose" the forwarding when entering tmux. How can "forward again" so that I can use my keys from within tmux?

```
$ ssh [server] -o ForwardAgent=yes
$ git pull       # Succeeds.
$ /bin/bash
$ git pull       # Still succeeds, despite new shell.
$ exit
$ tmux attach
$ git pull       # Permission denied (publickey)
```

Comment: I confirm if you launch an agent shared between all your sessions, it works. The documentation at http://bose.utmb.edu/Compu_Center/ssh/SSH_HOWTO.html > Configure ssh-agent Process explains a method to achieve this result.

Comment: Also relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75681/why-do-i-have-to-re-set-env-vars-in-tmux-when-i-re-attach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're attaching an already existing tmux session, the shell is not inheriting the environment variables from your login shell. Particularly, it won't inherit the ssh agent environment variables.

Try [this fix](http://www.deadman.org/sshscreen.php):

1. Create this script and put it in $HOME/.ssh/saveagent

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   SSHVARS="SSH_CLIENT SSH_TTY SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_CONNECTION DISPLAY"

   for var in ${SSHVARS} ; do
     echo "export $var=\"$(eval echo '$'$var)\""
   done 1>$HOME/.ssh/latestagent
   ```
2. Add it to your shell startup script. For instance if you use bash:

   ```
   echo '. ~/.ssh/saveagent' >> ~/.bash_login
   ```
3. After attaching the tmux, run `. $HOME/.ssh/latestagent`

See also [How can I run a script immediately after connecting via SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/how-can-i-run-a-script-immediately-after-connecting-via-ssh) and [Attach to tmux session and run a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86925/attach-to-tmux-session-and-run-a-command)

Comment: Send to .profile maybe, if you're trying to be compatible with other sh shells.

Comment: Great answer! A few issues I ran into: a - some of the environment variables contain spaces, so the line before last in the `saveagent` script should be: `echo "export $var=\"$(eval echo '$'$var)\""`. b - the `latestagent` script should be called with `source` instead of `sh`, so setting the variables will affect the calling shell. c - calling the `latestagent` script automatically upon attaching tmux can be done via the method described here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86925/attach-to-tmux-session-and-run-a-command

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I modified my answer to include your improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to source a script containing all the variables you need in every shell you further spawn in any new shell spawned by the same `tmux` server sessions, you will probably want to tell `tmux` to put the variables into the session or global environments with the `set-environment` command. For example like this (for bash):

```sh
for var in DISPLAY SSH_AUTH_SOCK ...; do
    tmux setenv "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

remember to add the `-g` flag if you want it in other sessions as well and to use `-t <session>` if you are running it from outside of `tmux`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the other answers here, I decided to just copy my public/private keypair to the remote server, so that I didn't need to worry about agent forwarding anymore.