# How to start tmux in a way that it inherits all environment variables from the calling shell?

Tags: tmux

After I have set up a development shell (e.g., by starting a PostgreSQL cluster with a particular configuration, exporting several environment variables, "installed" a bunch of applications via `nix-shell`), I want to start tmux where all everything from the calling shell is available.

By default, tmux ignores my environmnet variables, and all the solutions I've found spell out how one has to re-declare each variable again, one-by-one. (Could be wrong though as I'm also having trouble deciphering the [relevant section of the tmux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#GLOBAL_AND_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT).)

- [Why do I have to re-set env vars in tmux when I re-attach?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75681/why-do-i-have-to-re-set-env-vars-in-tmux-when-i-re-attach)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701757/tmux-setting-environment-variables-for-sessions

I like the static, declarative approach in production, but sometimes I just want to quickly hack away at stuff.

Answer (score 4):

[@Phluks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532238/phluks)' para-phrased [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645053/how-do-i-start-tmux-with-my-current-environment#comment23100473_8645053):

> This can be achieved using the '-L' (or '-S') option. These start a new server with the current environment. E.g., `tmux -L <arbitrary_name>` creates a new session in the server on that socket, with the same environment as in the calling shell. `tmux -L <arbitrary_name> list-sessions` will list the sessions on that particular server, etc.

For example:

```
$ export LOFA=27

$ tmux -L miez

...(tmux-session)... $ echo $LOFA
27
```